# EntitySetController multiple navigation properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a controller for a class that has multiple navigation properties :

```
public partial class Fixture
{
    public int FixtureId { get; set; }

    //foreign key
    public int StageId { get; set; }
    //navigation properties
    public virtual Stage Stage { get; set; }

    //foreign key
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    //navigation properties
    public virtual City City { get; set; }

    public DateTime FixtureDate { get; set; }

    //foreign key
    public int AwayTeamId { get; set; }
    //navigation properties
    public virtual Team AwayTeam { get; set; }

    //foreign key
    public int HomeTeamId { get; set; }
    //navigation properties
    public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }

    public byte? AwayTeamScore { get; set; }
    public byte? HomeTeamScore { get; set; }
}
```

I am now writing my first `EntitySetController` and I want to Include the 3 navigation properties. I know how to include one like like this :

```
public IQueryable<Fixture> GetFixtures()
{
    return db.Fixtures.Include("Stage");
}
```

Is it possible to Include more than one of these navigation properties?

Also, in my Post how do I use these to get the related objects?  In the previous version which was an `ApiController`, I wrote repository methods to get them (see below). What would be the `EntitySetController` equivalent?

```
public override HttpResponseMessage Post(Fixture fixture)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Stage stage = _repository.GetStageByStageId(fixture.StageId);
            City city = _repository.GetCityByCityId(fixture.CityId);
            Team awayTeam = _repository.GetTeamByTeamName(fixture.AwayTeamName);
            Team homeTeam = _repository.GetTeamByTeamName(fixture.HomeTeamName);

            Fixture entity = new Fixture();
            entity.StageId = stage.StageId;
            entity.CityId = city.CityId;
            entity.FixtureDate = fixture.FixtureDate;
            entity.AwayTeamId = awayTeam.TeamId;
            entity.HomeTeamId = homeTeam.TeamId;
            entity.AwayTeamScore = fixture.AwayTeamScore;
            entity.HomeTeamScore = fixture.HomeTeamScore;

            db.Fixtures.Add(fixture);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, fixture);
            //response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", 
            //                                new { id = fixture.FixtureId }));

            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

EDIT : I have used the multiple includes and referenced the navigation properties in the Post method :

```
public override HttpResponseMessage Post(Fixture fixture)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Fixture entity = new Fixture();
            entity.StageId = fixture.Stage.StageId;
            entity.CityId = fixture.City.CityId;
            entity.FixtureDate = fixture.FixtureDate;
            entity.AwayTeamId = fixture.AwayTeam.TeamId;
            entity.HomeTeamId = fixture.HomeTeam.TeamId;
            entity.AwayTeamScore = fixture.AwayTeamScore;
            entity.HomeTeamScore = fixture.HomeTeamScore;

            db.Fixtures.Add(entity);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, fixture);

            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

But I get a 400 Bad Request error and when I look into the object passed it looks like this

```
request: Object
body: "{"FixtureId":0,"StageId":0,"CityId":0,"FixtureDate":"2014-09-08T21:00:00.000","AwayTeamId":0,"HomeTeamId":0}"
callbackParameterName: "$callback"
data: Object
AwayTeam: undefined
AwayTeamId: 0
AwayTeamScore: undefined
City: undefined
CityId: 0
FixtureDate: "2014-09-08T21:00:00.000"
FixtureId: 0
HomeTeam: undefined
HomeTeamId: 0
HomeTeamScore: undefined
Stage: undefined
StageId: 0
```

The UI looks like this, and all the dropdowns are populated successfully :

```
    <div data-ng-app="app" ng-controller="FixtureAddController">
    <form name="form" class="col-xs-2" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: form.StageName.$invalid}">
            <label class="control-label" for="StageName">Stage Team</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="fixture.StageName" ng-options="stage.StageName as stage.StageName for stage in stages" required>
                    <option style="display:none" value="">Select</option>
                </select>
                <span ng-show="form.StageName.$dirty && form.StageName.$error.required">Stage required</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: form.CityName.$invalid}">
            <label class="control-label" for="CityName">City</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="fixture.CityName" ng-options="city.CityName as city.CityName for city in cities" required>
                    <option style="display:none" value="">Select</option>
                </select>
                <span ng-show="form.CityName.$dirty && form.CityName.$error.required">City required</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: form.FixtureDate.$invalid}">
            <label class="control-label" for="BirthDate">Fixture Date</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type='text' class="form-control" ng-model='fixture.FixtureDate' name='FixtureDate' title="FixtureDate" ng-pattern='/^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/' required />
                <span ng-show='form.FixtureDate.$dirty && form.FixtureDate.$error.required'>Fixture Date required</span>
                <span ng-show='form.FixtureDate.$dirty && form.FixtureDate.$error.pattern'>Fixture Date invalid</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: form.HomeTeamName.$invalid}">
            <label class="control-label" for="HomeTeamName">Home Team</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="fixture.HomeTeamName" ng-options="team.TeamName as team.TeamName for team in teams" required>
                    <option style="display:none" value="">Select</option>
                </select>
                <span ng-show="form.HomeTeamName.$dirty && form.HomeTeamName.$error.required">Home Team required</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: form.AwayTeamName.$invalid}">
            <label class="control-label" for="AwayTeamName">Away Team</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="fixture.AwayTeamName" ng-options="team.TeamName as team.TeamName for team in teams" required>
                    <option style="display:none" value="">Select</option>
                </select>
                <span ng-show="form.AwayTeamName.$dirty && form.AwayTeamName.$error.required">Away Team required</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button ng-show="form.$valid" ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-primary">{{action}}</button>
            <a href="/Admin/Fixtures/List" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

How would I successfully do the Post?

EDIT 2 : When I for example change in the UI `fixture.CityId` to `fixture.City.CityName` to bind the value in the dropdown to the fixture object, when I Post I get the following error :

```
Exception {name: "HTTP request failed", message: "{"$id":"1","Message":"No HTTP resource was found t…http://lovelyjubbly.cloudapp.net/odata/$batch'."}", data: Object, stack: (...), _getStackTrace: function…}
data: Object
message: "HTTP request failed"
request: Object
body: "
↵--batch_c20a-c604-4067
↵Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_3cce-3259-213d
↵
↵--changeset_3cce-3259-213d
↵Content-Type: application/http
↵Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
↵
↵POST Cities HTTP/1.1
↵Content-Id: 1
↵MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0
↵DataServiceVersion: 3.0
↵Accept: application/atomsvc+xml;q=0.8, application/json;odata=verbose;q=0.5, */*;q=0.1
↵Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose
↵
↵{"CityId":0,"CityName":"Brasilia"}
↵--changeset_3cce-3259-213d
↵Content-Type: application/http
↵Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
↵
↵POST Fixtures HTTP/1.1
↵Content-Id: 2
↵MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0
↵DataServiceVersion: 3.0
↵Accept: application/atomsvc+xml;q=0.8, application/json;odata=verbose;q=0.5, */*;q=0.1
↵Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose
↵
↵{"FixtureId":0,"StageId":0,"CityId":0,"FixtureDate":"2012-11-10T22:00:00.000","AwayTeamId":0,"HomeTeamId":0,"City":{"__metadata":{"uri":"$1"}}}
↵--changeset_3cce-3259-213d--
↵
↵--batch_c20a-c604-4067--
↵"
callbackParameterName: "$callback"
data: Object
__batchRequests: Array[1]
0: Object
__changeRequests: Array[2]
0: Object
body: "{"CityId":0,"CityName":"Brasilia"}"
data: Object
headers: Object
method: "POST"
requestUri: "Cities"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
body: "{"FixtureId":0,"StageId":0,"CityId":0,"FixtureDate":"2012-11-10T22:00:00.000","AwayTeamId":0,"HomeTeamId":0,"City":{"__metadata":{"uri":"$1"}}}"
data: Object
headers: Object
method: "POST"
requestUri: "Fixtures"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your first question - yes, you can include more than one navigation property.

```
return db.Fixtures
    .Include("Stage")
    .Include("FixtureDate")
    .Include("AwayTeam");
```

etc

EDIT
As for your second question - if you've defined your `Fixtures` class as having those navigation properties, and the load from db brings back the complete graph with all the relevant 'includes', then that model should still be intact after the Controller>View>Controller flow.
Which means you should be able to just access the data like `Fixture.AwayTeam.Name` (or whatever a property of `AwayTeam` might look like).

You can also submit the changes for a complete model/graph to EntityFramework, but with a disconnected graph like this you will need to have a strategy of how to set EntityState correctly for each part of the graph otherwise you can get errors when doing things like:
- submitting a new Fixture that uses existing AwayTeam (EF will attempt to create a new AwayTeam rather than link the existing AwayTeam to the new Fixture)
- submitting an edited Fixture and an edited AwayTeam

EDIT 2
Sorry, just realised I was bringing in EF and your question wasn't about EF. Ignore the EF specifics!

Comment: Regarding the second question, if I want to create a FixtureDTO that would include for example the actual StageName rather than the foreign key StageId, can I use Get/Fixture(5)/Stage in my Post method (and if so what would be the syntax), or would I use the type of methods I use above? Also, is it a good idea to use multiple Includes to get all the foreign key data, will this not slow down execution?

Comment: RE: good idea to use multiple includes. That really depends on your needs. Yes, it will increase your data transfer because you are now bringing in more than just the base entity. But if you need the information contained within the include then you need to bring it back.

Comment: Please see Edit above

Comment: In your Post method above, have you inspected whether the *incoming* `Fixture` has the data you expect to see from the view?

Comment: Please see Edit 2, I have changed the UI to bind the fixture object to incorporate the navigation properties.  Why is it trying to Post to Cities as well as Fixtures and how do I prevent this and populate the Fixture with the City instead?